# How do I place content in a user-profile.tpl.php, based on whether a boolean field is true?

Tags: users

I am trying to display certain content in the user profile pages of a site based on whether my boolean field 'member' is true. I am currently trying to solve this with an if statement like so.

```
    if ($user_profile['field_member']['und']['0']['value'] == '1') {

        print ('<p>This is working</p>');

    }
```

However this is returning an

'Undefined index: und in include()'

error on the if statement line. I'm not very well versed in working with drupal template files and would appreciate any help.

EDIT: The syntax was incorrect I should of written '#items' instead of 'und'. I discovered this with advisement, through the use of the devel kpr() function which allowed me to view the array contents more easily than a var dump.

Comment: just check `$user_profile['field_member']['und']['0']['value']` contains a value..??

Comment: I dumped the $user_profile variable and I'm pretty sure it does, but I can post the dump if it helps?

Comment: if so `$user_profile['field_member']['und'][0]['value']` has to work..

Comment: install devel module and use `kpr()` function to get the exact syntax

Comment: Thanks, I installed Devel, used the recommended function, and got it working. It was under #items

Comment: @Kingswipe1 - Please add an expanded explanation as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't access data that way, especially in template files as it's the raw data.

You should use the functions [field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) & [field_view_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_value/7)

Comment: Thanks for this, I would appreciate insight as to why its a bad idea to access the raw data in this manner? Is it a security risk or just bad practice?

Comment: See https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way for a detailed explanation, etc.